# Что значит эта часть кода в php?

Tags: php, laravel

Что значит `old('permissions', [])` ?

```
<select class="form-control select2 {{ $errors->has('permissions') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="permissions[]" id="permissions" multiple required>
    @foreach($permissions as $id => $permissions)

        <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ (in_array($id, old('permissions', [])) || $role->permissions->contains($id)) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $permissions }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это функция для получения старого ввода.
Из документации:

> Для получения переданного ввода из предыдущего запроса используйте
>   метод old() на экземпляре Request. Метод old() получит переданные
>   ранее данные ввода из сессии

```
$username = $request->old('username');
```

> В Laravel есть глобальная  вспомогательная функция old(). Когда вы выводите 
>   старый ввод в шаблоне
>   Blade, удобнее использовать эту функцию old. Если для данного поля нет
>   старого ввода, вернётся null

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
```

[Ссылка](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#old-input) на документацию

В вашем коде проверяется существует ли `id` в массиве возвращаемой функцией `old()`

Comment: А как мне распечатать old('permissions', []) и посмотреть что она вернула ?

Comment: `dump(old('permissions', []));` ??

Comment: Ошибка Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /home/mavrin/laravel-dev/CRM/resources/views/admin/roles/edit.blade.php)

Comment: Вот по этой ссылке ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217872/laravel-htmlspecialchars-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-object-given